# check duplicates in binary tree

Tags: algorithm, duplicates, binary-tree

How can I check that my binary tree doens't contain duplicates?
Do you have an algorithm?
Please write the pseudocode

**EDIT:** or (better) using math property.
This is my Tree over an alphabet A: (a,U,V) where a \in A and U and V is respectively the left child and the right child.

If the tree is ordered like a binary search tree using a relation of ordering < (riflessive, antisymmetric, transitive, total) I can express that T=(a,U,V) is ordered without duplicates IFONLY `\forall u \in flatten(U) and \forall v \in flatten(V). u < a< v and u \neq a and a \neq v` and i've to check the property recursively for the tree U and tree tree V. But the question is: How can i check that the tree doesn't contains duplicates if the tree is not ordered (or is not a binary search tree)?

*Apologise for my first not clear question*

**EDIT2:** flatten is the function that return the set of the elements of the parameter tree

Comment: .... _Currently studing at University of Genoa, Italy_. lolz, just say that it's a homework question and you'll be sorted!!

Comment: the tree is given or you create it?

Comment: I've Bachelor of Science in Information Technology and I'm doing something like homework on Category theory but it's very different from cut and paste the pseudocode.

Comment: as it looks like the Q is gonna close, a quick clue to help out. would the duplicates need to be removed at the 'leaf' level, or are we talking about no duplicates across the entire structure?? this really makes a difference to the answer. i'm kinda surprised at the lack of effort you've put in to making your question crystal clear. sorry, that's just how i see it (i didn't downvote you btw - but can see why others may have)

Comment: no duplicates across the entire structure. Maybe I should have posted my question in math.stackexchange.com because my "homework" is something like "take all binary trees and define them as a category, and define the functor and other complex (very complex for me) categories". So this question is half based on programming data type and half based on math. now i'm going to improve my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an O(n log n) obvious way, you collect the elements, sort the list and find duplicates. The problem is at least as hard as finding duplicates in an array see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem). Therefore, if you rely only on comparisons, you cannot achieve better than O(n log n).

Comment: Please prove or outline a prove that finding duplicates in a binary tree is as hard as in a list/vector. After all, the in-order iteration of a binary tree is `O(n)` and gives you a sorted list, in which duplicate detection is `O(n)`.

Comment: Given an algorithm A that takes a binary tree and returns YES/NO indicating whether there are duplicates. One can get an algorithm for determining uniqueness in lists by just putting the elements in a linear tree (takes linear time) and passing this tree to A.

Comment: Granted, this is true for a non-ordered tree, and the OP didn't specify a *search* tree. (OTOH, the linear tree is so utterly useless in 99% of all cases that I have totally forgotten about its existence.) The original question needs improvement, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If the input is bounded, say, between the values 1 to 1000 then you can use an array, which we call `A`.
Go over each node with value `val` and let `A[val]=1`.
This way you mark all the elements that you encounter.
This one runs in `O(n)` and uses additional `1000` elements of space.